# Not able to Connect to a named instance remotely

Tags: sql-server

I have a server with 2 SQL Server instances, I can connect to the default instance remotely, however I am not able to connect to the named instance.

[image]

[image]

[image]

When I try to connect remotely, I get this error, SQL Server is configured to allow remote connection and the name is correct

[image]

Comment: Does DNS for 311SQLI01 resolve correctly on your client?

Comment: I think that are like thousands of questions like this here.

Comment: @JimG.  yes it is resolved correctly

Comment: @RafaelPiccinelli .. can you give me 5 links for  these thousands of questions

Comment: @sebeid - see the "related" links to the right of your question.

Comment: @MaxVernon i was already checked these links but nothing was the same as my question  but thanks for your comment .. just curious are you and Rafael Friends :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try connecting to `311SQLI01,1430`.  If that works, turn on the SQL Browser service.

SQL Browser needs to be turned on for port number translation ( it's off in your screenshot ) and you don't seem to be referencing the specific port in your connection attempts.